# Gdata spreadsheet API multi-threading (python)

Tags: multithreading, google-docs, gdata, google-docs-api, gdata-api

Does anyone know if you can multithread google docs spreadsheet writes using python's gdata spreadsheet api?

I have a database of spreadsheets that need to be updated daily, and it would be nice to distribute the writes over multiple cores for speedup..

Thanks in advance to anyone with knowledge on the subject. My biggest concern is whether a single google account can write two (or more) things simultaneously (though, they are shared docs so I could have multiple accounts -- one for each core...)

Thanks again